# How to Rotate only some UIViews on interface orientation change

Tags: ios, uiwebview, orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

Please have a look at the several orientations in the image below to get what I want to achieve (rotation of a `UIWebView` which takes up all the screen space and buttons inside a toolbar (which is a `UIView` overlaying the WebView and should always stay on the bottom of the device) . I read through several somehow similar questions here, but they weren't dealing with nested views so I don't know how to accomplish this behavior best. How would you solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: check out my answer it is similar to what you want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25116967/youtube-video-directly-not-playing-to-landscape-mode-ios-7/25119235#25119235

Comment: I checked it out but I can't see how this is will help me? Can you please tell me how you would rotate only the buttons and the webview

Comment: but i don't want to rotate whole view! ... only webview and buttons but NOT the toolbar the buttons are in